# Java - Editing an Array of JLabels

Tags: java, arrays, swing, set, jlabel

When ran, the code produces an error and does not create the 4x4 panel of JLabels. The reference of this method is located in my constructor above. Why won't my JLabel array be displayed?

```
public void createLabels()
    {
        pnlBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4, 5,5));
        for(int i = 0; i <= 16; i++)
        {
            lblBoard[i] = new JLabel("");
            lblBoard[i].setOpaque(true);
            lblBoard[i].setBackground(Color.magenta);
            lblBoard[i].setForeground(Color.white);
            lblBoard[i].setFont(font1);
            lblBoard[i].addMouseListener(this);
            lblBoard[i].setName("" + i);
            pnlBoard.add(lblBoard[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `"... the code produces an error..."` -- and you **are** planning to share that error message with us, right?

Comment: Note, this `i <= 16;` should be `i < 16;`

Comment: I already explained, the code produces an error on this method. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: `"I already explained, the code produces an error on this method"` -- But you don't tell us or show us what the error is. Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Please have a look at [help] as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections for more information on how to improve your question and increase your chances of getting decent help.

Comment: The error has been solved, but my JLabel array is still not being displayed. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: What error has been solved? How are we supposed to guess why something is not being displayed based on the limited information that you've posted? Have you read the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) links yet? Please do so before this question gets closed for being unanswerable.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't even be using "magic" numbers like 16, and instead should be using `lblBoard.length`. Otherwise you risk an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error which I'm guessing was your "error".

Comment: I have and am trying to ask a decent question. The error being displayed when I ran the program was the i <= 16. It needed to be plainly i < 16. However, the 4x4 panel is still not being displayed, even without errors. HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Please re-read the links, especially the [mcve] section. Your posted code gives us no clues as to why your JLabels are not displaying, and so I can say with confidence that no one will be able to answer or help until you improve this question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you, but this is the only part of my code that would contain an error. I understand if you can not help. Someone else might be able to figure it out. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: There is no other area of code not working. The only issue I am having with my code, is not having the panel display. That section of code is displayed above. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Look up [mcve]. If my answer below does not solve the question, then create and post your [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

One problem, perhaps this:

```
lblBoard[i].setName("" + i);
```

should be:

```
lblBoard[i].setText("" + i);
```

Why would you want to set the name of the JLabel field? The text however, that you'd probably like to change (is my guess).